# "could not find function" when using foreach in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I know there are many similar questions in stackoverflow. But I think this problem may be a little different.

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

fun1 <- function(x) {
  return(sqrt(x))
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  return(sin(x))
}

fun3 <- function(x, FUN, .export = NULL, .packages = NULL) {
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  res <- foreach(i = seq(x), .export = .export, .packages = .packages) %dopar% FUN(i)
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(res)
}

fun4 <- function(x, FUN, .export = NULL, .packages = NULL) {
  return(fun3(x, FUN = function(x) fun2(match.fun(FUN)(x)), .export = .export, .packages = .packages))
}
```

There is error "could not find function 'fun2'", when I run `fun4`.

```
res <- fun4(10^3, fun1, .export = c("fun2"))
```

How can I specify the `.export` parameter?

Comment: You will need to clusterExport functions that are required by all clusters

Comment: I tried `clusterExport` function. It works.